# Can anyone explain the below code please

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

`where client.name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())

Comment: Looks like it would always return `true`.  What are the datatypes of `client` and `client.name`?

Comment: How can a string variable have a string member

Comment: Seems strange. Unless the client object implements a ToLower method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it's clearer. It's a (badly done) case insensitive search for the `name` in the `client.name`. True if `name` is contained in `client.name`. Badly done because using international letters (clearly "international letters" don't exist. I mean letters from a culture different from you own. The classical example is the Turkish culture. Read this: http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html , the part titled `Turkish Has An Important Difference`), you can break it. The "right" way to do it is: `client.name.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1`. Instead of `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` you can use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`. If you have to use tricks like the `ToLower`, it has been suggested that it's better to `ToUpper` both sides of the comparison (but it's MUCH better to use `StringComparison.*`)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594) to me.

I'm not really up-to-date on .NET these days, but I'd read that as looking for `client` objects whose `name` property is a case-insensitive match with the `ToString` property of the `client` variable, while allowing additional characters before or after, much like `WHERE foo is like '%:some_value%'` in SQL. If I'm right, btw, `client` is a terrible variable name in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange piece of code.  It would be good to know a bit more about the client object.  Essentially it is checking if the case insensitive name value on the client object contains the case insensitive value of the client object (as a string).  So if the client name contains the string name of the class itself essentially.

Answer (score 1):

.ToLower() returns the same string you call it on in all lowercase letters. Basically, this statement returns true if name.ToLower() is embedded anywhere within client.name.ToLower().

```
//If:<br/>
client.name = "nick, bob, jason";
name = "nick";
//Then:<br/>
client.name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower());
//would return true
```